# Netty SimpleChannelInboundHandler close channel

Tags: java, websocket, netty

I have handler that extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler. I use it for handling websocket frames.
What is the best way to detect that connection was closed from client side (for browser closed or network connection crashed)?
I see there are two methods in ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter: channelUnregistered and channelInactive. Can I use its for detectiong channel closing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `channelInactive()` which is triggered when a channel cannot perform communication anymore.  `channelUnregistered()` has different meaning although `channelUnregistered()` is always triggered after `channelInactive()`.

Comment: I've overrided both channelUnregistered and channelInactive in my handler. And none of them are triggered never. What could be the reason?

Comment: @ismailyavuz Probably because one of the handlers placed before your handler did not forward the event by calling `ctx.fireChannelInactive()` or `ctx.fireChannelUnregistered()`?

Comment: I only have these 4 in my initChannel to add the pipeline. 1)DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder as framer, 2)StringDecoder as decoder 3)StringEncoder as encoder 4) my own handler which extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> @trustin

Comment: what about "close" callback, what's the diff between close and channelInactive

Answer (score 0):

`channelUnregistered()` is also called in case of an unsuccessful connection attempt. So `channelInactive()` seems to be the better choice to listen to connection closed events.

I just saw this when implementing a reconnection strategy, where a closed connection would trigger a reconnect. `channelUnregistered()` was my first choice and obviously wrong, because it would re-trigger a reconnect after each reconnect, endlessly.

Btw: I also tested with websocket connections.

Answer (score -1):

with netty 4 i use `channelUnregistered`

maybe you are worried about the warning on the log, i solved it changing the log level because it is already handled by the method but always appear

```
<logger name="io.netty" additivity="false">
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
```